# Erroneous application of AM-GM inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> For positive reals $x,y,z, \ x>3$, satisfying $x+y+z=60$, maximize $(x-3)(2y+1)(3z+5)$

From the AM-GM inequality for positive reals,

$$
\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq (a\cdot b \cdot c)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Equality for this expression (and hence maximum for the geometric mean) is attained when $a=b=c$.

Applied here it gives me 2 equations:

$$x-3 = 2y+1  \\ 2y+1=3z+5$$

Added with the constraint $x+y+z=60$, we can solve for $x,y,z$.

We get $x=\frac{388}{11},\ y = \frac{172}{11}, \ z= \frac{100}{11}$.

So it means that:

$$max\{(x-3)(2y+1)(3z+5)\} = \frac{355^3}{11^3} \approx 33612.9$$

Whereas my book states that the maximum is instead $\frac{355^3}{9\cdot 36} \approx 138083.9$.

Where is my error? How do I proceed?

Comment: Firstly, you can't apply AM-GM because $x-3$ might be negative. Secondly, $AM \ge GM$ does not mean that you can maximize GM by making a,b,c equal - note that the AM varies as a,b,c vary within the constraint. You could try using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: $x>3$ was given, so $x-3$ can not be negative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Equality for this expression (and hence maximum for the geometric mean) is attained when $a=b=c$.

This is where the error lies. For example, pick any three positive numbers $a'\ge b'\ge c'$ that are not all equal to each other. Then pick some positive number $c''$ such that $c'<c''<(a'b'c')^{1/3}$. Let $a''=b''=c''$. Then

$$\left(\frac{a'+b'+c'}{3}\right)^3
>a'b'c'>a''b''c''
=\left(\frac{a''+b''+c''}{3}\right)^3.$$

By our choice of $a'',b''$ and $c''$, we have $a'>a''=b''=c''>c'$. Therefore the vector $\mathbf v=(a'-a'',b'-b'',c'-c'')$ contains both positive and negative entries. Hence there exists a positive vector $\mathbf p=(p_1^{-1},p_2^{-1},p_3^{-1})$ such that $\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf v=0$. Now pick any three real numbers $q_1,q_2,q_3$ such that $q_1<\min(a',a''),\,q_2<\min(b',b'')$ and $q_3<\min(c',c'')$. Define
\begin{align*}
x'&=p_1^{-1}(a'-q_1),\quad y'=p_2^{-1}(b'-q_2),\quad z'=p_3^{-1}('c-q_3),\\
x''&=p_1^{-1}(a''-q_1),\quad y''=p_2^{-1}(b''-q_2),\quad z''=p_3^{-1}(c''-q_3).\\
\end{align*}
Then $(x',y',z')$ and $(x'',y'',z'')$ are positive vectors, and $x'+y'+z'=x''+y''+z''$ because the difference between the two sides is precisely equal to $\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf v$, which is zero. Let $S=x'+y'+z'$ and consider the following optimization problem:

> Maximize $(p_1x+q_1)(p_2y+q_2)(p_3z+q_3)$ subject to the constraints $x,y,z,\,p_1x+q_1,\,p_2y+q_2,\,p_3z+q_3>0$ and $x+y+z=S$.

Both $(x',y',z')$ and $(x'',y'',z'')$ are feasible solutions. While the AM-GM inequality is strict for the triple $(a',b',c')$, equality holds for $(a'',b'',c'')$. However, $(x',y',z')$ is more optimal than $(x'',y'',z'')$ because $a'b'c'>a''b''c''$.

However the idea of exploiting the equality case in the AM-GM inequality **does** work when it is applied appropriately and when situation allows. In general, consider an optimization problem in the following form:

> Let $S,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,p_1,p_2,p_3>0$ and $q_1,q_2,q_3\in\mathbb R$. Maximize $f(x,y,z)=(p_1x+q_1)(p_2y+q_2)(p_3z+q_3)$ subject to the constraints $x,y,z,\,p_1x+q_1,\,p_2y+q_2,\,p_3z+q_3>0$ and $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=S$.

Let $a=\alpha x+\frac{\alpha q_1}{p_1},\, b=\beta y+\frac{\alpha q_2}{p_2} ,\, c=\alpha z+\frac{\alpha q_3}{p_3}$ and $T=S+\frac{\alpha q_1}{p_1}+\frac{\beta q_2}{p_2}+\frac{\gamma q_3}{p_3}$. If $T$ happens to be positive, we may consider the **relaxed** problem of maximizing $abc$ subject to $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=T$. This is almost equivalent to the original problem except that $x,y,z$ are not required to be positive. By the AM-GM inequality we have
$$abc\leq\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3.$$
Since $a+b+c=T$ is a **constant**, $abc$ is maximised when the constant upper bound $\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3$ is attained, i.e., when equality holds in the AM-GM inequality. Hence the optimal solution to the relaxed problem is given by $a=b=c=\frac{T}{3}$. If the values of $x,y$ and $z$ recovered from $a,b$ and $c$ are positive, $(x,y,z)$ will be an optimal solution to the original problem.

---

*(I always visit this site using the Tor Browser. Probably due to a code change on this site, I am told that "Editing is currently forbidden". I cannot edit my answer to fix any possible error and I cannot respond to comments. I apologize for any inconvenience caused.)*

Comment: Ramen: see [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=tor) for issues using Tor, seems they block some actions to prevent abuse; also heuristics depends on your account (e.g. >125 rep). Post your issue there if needs.

Answer (score 6):

First,
$$ (x-3)(2y+1)(3z+5) = 6 (x-3)(y+\frac{1}{2})(z+\frac{5}{3}). $$
Then, by AM-GM,
$$ (x-3)(y+\frac{1}{2})(z+\frac{3}{5}) \leqslant (\frac{1}{3}((x-3)+(y+\frac{1}{2})+(z+\frac{5}{3})))^3 = (\frac{1}{3} (x+y+z) - \frac{5}{18})^3 = \frac{44738875}{5832}. $$
Finally,
$$ \max{(x-3)(2y+1)(3z+5)} = 6 \times \frac{44738875}{5832} = \frac{44738875}{972} $$

Comment: You didn't answer what was wrong in my approach though.

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma If you set $a=x-3, b=2y+1, c=3z+5$ in the AM-GM, then $a+b+c$ does not contain a $x+y+z$.

Comment: My question still remains. When we consider $x-3$,$y+1/2$, $z+5/3$, we can set all three of them equal to each other and obtain a correct set of values for $x,y,z$ that maximize their geometric mean. Why not the same applicable for $x-3$,$2y+1$,$3z+5$?

Comment: @SahajSatishSharma - The geometric mean itself does not have a maximum. If you increase the values of $x,y,z$, the geometric mean will keep increasing. It is the condition that $x + y + z = 60$ (and the lower limits on $x,y,z$) that limits the size of the geometric mean. Your approach finds the maximum when $(x-3) + (2y+1) + (3z+5)$ has a fixed value. But that is not the condition given. It is $x + y + z$ that is fixed, not $x +2y + 3z$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thank you for the response. It sums it up quite well.